# How do I install/update drivers on Debian 9?

Tags: linux, debian, drivers

I just installed Debian 9 on my laptop, however Wifi isn't working and I'm not sure if my graphic card is either. I'm sure that it's just a lack of drivers, but I've never actually had to update drivers on Linux before. So how do I do that?

Comment: What hardware do you have?  Unless you need/want proprietary drivers (Nvidia) or need to use `ndiswrapper` (some network cards, especially wireless) then things should Just Work

Comment: Have you tried to google the model and brand of your computer?

Answer (score 12):

In Debian, if you run into issues with wi-fi or graphics support, there are usually two things to check.

The first is the kernel, especially for graphics. You can usually get a newer kernel by looking at [backports](https://backports.debian.org/); currently, [the Debian 9 kernel is 4.9.320](https://packages.debian.org/source/stretch/linux), but [4.19.118 is available as a backport](https://packages.debian.org/source/stretch-backports/linux) with better support for newer graphics adapters. This is particularly true for Intel GPUs. To install a kernel from backports, proceed as follows:

1. Add the backports repository:

   ```
    echo deb http://http.debian.net/debian stretch-backports main contrib non-free > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list
   ```

   On Debian 10, replace `stretch` with `buster`; on Debian 11, with `bullseye`.

   (Yes, we’re adding `contrib` and `non-free`, they’ll come in handy later...)
2. Install the backported kernel:

   ```
    apt update
    apt -t stretch-backports install linux-image-amd64
   ```

   This won’t replace your current kernel, so you can always boot that instead if things go wrong. Again, use `buster-backports` instead of `stretch-backports` on Debian 10, and `bullseye-backports` on Debian 11.

The second is firmware. Most GPUs, and many wi-fi adapters, need firmware, which might not be installed by default (because source code is generally not available, so it’s not made available as part of Debian, but instead in the `non-free` repositories). To install the available firmware, from backports too (might as well):

```
apt install -t stretch-backports firmware-linux
```

As before, use `buster-backports` instead of `stretch-backports` on Debian 10, and `bullseye-backports` on Debian 11.

In both cases, reboot to pick up the new or improved hardware support...

Comment: Hi, I tried this solution as you suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/501921/intel-hd-graphics-is-not-working-with-debian-stretch?noredirect=1#comment925140_501921). This solved everything discribed in the question (Thank you very much) but the screen tearing was still there. As a blind shot, I ran `apt-get -t stretch-backports upgrade` and surprisingly it worked. Now is there any way to find which exact package solved it?

Comment: I imagine it would be the Mesa packages (see [the other answer I’d linked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478943/installing-mesa-18-from-stretch-backports)); the `apt` logs in `/var/log/apt` will tell you what was upgraded, you’d then have to read the changelogs to attempt to identify a likely candidate.

Comment: It must be. I remember that I see 'mesa' while upgrading. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

Open up a terminal and try

```
lspci -kv | less
```

Here you can look at all your PCI devices. I notice in my output these two devices:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV670 [Radeon HD 3870] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Dell RV670 [Radeon HD 3870]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at fe9f0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    I/O ports at dc00 [size=256]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    *Kernel driver in use: radeon*
    *Kernel modules: radeon*

04:05.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT2800 802.11n PCI
    Subsystem: Edimax Computer Co. RT2800 802.11n PCI
    Flags: bus master, slow devsel, latency 64, IRQ 17
    Memory at fe7f0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    *Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci*
    *Kernel modules: rt2800pci*
```

Take note of what the name of the device is, e.g. **Radeon HD3870**. See that I have appropriate drivers/modules listed (asterisks around them are mine) - what have you got?

Debian favour free software over guaranteed full function out of the box. If your wifi is not working, connect over ethernet and fix your problems first. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Recently issued the same problem and after four days of an experiment :

## First things first:

*Reconfigure sources.list:*

```
su  
rm /etc/apt/sources.list  
editor /etc/apt/sources.list
```

*then add (contrib + non-free):*

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
```

### **Configure Sudo**

*Login as root and install sudo*

```
su  
apt-get install sudo
```

*Now add your subuser to sudo users and use that user from now on.*

```
adduser $USER sudo
```

### **Update**

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade -y
```

---

### Examine, *other* possible firmware missing:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

### Identify the Packages:

```
apt-cache search firmware.bin
```

or

```
apt-file search firmware.bin
```

### Search for Graphic Adapters:

```
lspci -nn | grep VGA
```

*or*

```
spci -nn | grep '\[03'
```

*or*

```
sudo dmesg | grep -E 'drm|radeon' | grep -iE 'firmware|microcode'
```

*or*

*https://kmuto.jp/debian/hcl/index.rhtmlx*

## Install microcode

for Intel CPU, `sudo apt install intel-microcode`
*(for Intel i686 and Intel X86-64 processors)*

for AMD64 `sudo apt install amd64-microcode`*(necessary to install with graphics **AMD only**)*

## Install AMD Graphics in Debian 9.7

```
sudo apt install firmware-amd-graphics
```

*or*

```
apt-get install firmware-linux-nonfree libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-video-ati
```

*Reboot*

```
sudo reboot
```

## Enjoy!

Comment: Every step should BE PRECISELY made it for to AMD Graphics in new Debian 9.7, note this is only for AMD(open source) and (not fglrx and/or any NVIDIA).

Comment: I only don't understand the malice behind of down vote of my answer, I've TESTED and I'm using in my machine right now, a part is updated and related to the recently manual Debian 9.7, other possibilites has been discarded, since is old and could harm your OS.

Comment: you guys are thinking that I'll change my answer and I'm REALLY will not! Call the admin for more support. I read all debian manual from the official website. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know why @Satoshi Nakamoto got down voted, It's helpful info, I just applied this to Debian 11 Bullseye that I was having trouble with missing video drivers, and it worked fine.

Comment: thanks for your answer, saved me a lot of headache.