# Installing Mesa 18 from stretch-backports

Tags: debian, backports

I want to install mesa 18 from `stretch-backports`. Currently all the mesa related packages were marked as automatically installed and I want to keep it that way.

If I simply do

```
$ sudo apt upgrade -t stretch-backports
```

It updates mesa but also too many other programs. Is there way to only upgrade packages coming from the `mesa` source package? Or maybe apt-pin based on source package instead of binary package?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should always avoid upgrading using `-t stretch-backports` since backports aren’t a coherent set of packages.

To upgrade all Mesa packages without marking them as manually installed, install them and then unmark them:

```
sudo apt install -t stretch-backports $(grep-status -S mesa -a -FStatus "install ok installed" -s Package -n | sort -u)
sudo apt-mark auto $(grep-status -S mesa -a -FStatus "install ok installed" -s Package -n | sort -u)
```

This lists all installed packages which come from the Mesa source package, using `grep-status` (part of the `dctrl-tools` package), installs them from backports, and marks them as automatically installed.

Comment: Hi, can you please explain this - "backports aren’t a coherent set of packages"

Comment: @Anees see [the introduction to backports](https://backports.debian.org/). Full releases of Debian are tested as a whole; backports are tested as small sets of packages (typically the packages from a single source package) on top of the release they target, without consideration for other backported packages. As a result, there’s no guarantee that backported packages will work well with each other.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Note that I had to install `dctrl-tools` first in order to get this working.