# Intel HD Graphics is not working with Debian Stretch

Tags: debian, drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, proprietary-drivers

Here is my system specifications

**Processor**: Intel Core i7-8700 Processor

**GPU**: Intel® UHD Graphics 630

**OS**: Debian 9.6 (Stretch)

**Monitor resolution**: 1920 x 1084

Even though I have a full HD monitor, I can't set a resolution higher than 1024x768.

The display is labelled as "Unknown Display".

xrandr shows a warning "xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default"

GPU usage is always 0% (Checked using intel-gpu-tools)

Experiencing screen tearing.

When searching online, most of the solution says to enable Jessie backports. Since I am already on stretch, I think I don't have to do it. How am I supposed to solve it, then? does intel provides any drivers?

---

### Edit

For those who has the same issue, try [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/420682/307224) answer as suggested by *@Stephen Kitt*. It worked for me.

Comment: The linked duplicate about drivers isn’t Intel-specific but [my answer there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/420682/86440) explains how to update your kernel and firmware, using the Stretch backports, which should fix problems with Intel graphics. You may also need to update Mesa, see the second link.

Comment: @StephenKitt Hi, Thanks for the link. As I've mentioned in the post, in jessie, enabling backports would solve the issue. As far as know, jessie backport packages are taken from the future version which is stretch(Plz correct me if i'm wrong) and it would have been working for me already.

Comment: Stretch backports aren’t Jessie backports; they’re backports from what will be Buster, to Stretch. The packages there are newer than the packages in Stretch. The terminology can be confusing: “Jessie backports” are backports of packages for Jessie (from Stretch); “Stretch backports” are backports for Stretch (from Buster).

Comment: @StephenKitt Didn't the issue fixed in stretch and jessie backports already? That's what I am asking.

Comment: Oh, OK, I get it. Since you’re having problems with your display I’d say it’s not fixed. The newer kernel in Stretch backports includes many fixes for Intel graphics, you don’t have much to lose (apart from your time) by trying it.

Comment: @StephenKitt Got it. May be the GPU wasn't supported in streatch but may be supported in buster or stretch backports, right?

Comment: Exactly. You have a Coffee Lake system which will have better support with a 4.19 kernel than a 4.9 kernel.