# Problems installing wifi driver on Debian 9

Tags: debian, wifi, realtek

I have Lenovo Legion y530 laptop. I try to turn on wifi this way:

type `lspci -nn | grep Network`, see this wireless adapter:

```
Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b822]
```

and by [10ec:b822] I find this driver on drivers.ru, that's

```
Realtek 8822BE Wireless LAN 802.11ac PCI-E NIC
```

but there is no wifi icon in system tray, dispite the fact that `network-manager-gnome` installed. Okay, I update kernel to 4.19.16 as says [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420678/how-do-i-install-update-drivers-on-debian-9/420682#420682). After reboot, icon appears, but it says wifi off & unawaitable. By loading, log says:

```
failed to load rtlwifi/rtl8822befw.bin (-2)
```

okay, I downloaded file `rtl8822befw.bin` & put it into folder `/lib/firmware/rtlwifi`, as says [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/926364/how-to-make-my-pci-wifi-card-rtl8822-working-on-ubuntu), than reboot. sign about fail to load rtlwifi disappears, but wifi still not awaitable.

What will advice to do after?

UPD: when I typing

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
```

terminal returns

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b822]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:b023]
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:38b4]
```

Comment: sorry for mistake :)

Comment: what is the output of `sudo modprobe -rv r8822be ; sudo modprobe -v r8822be` , it should print `insmod .. r8822be.ko` , no?

Answer (score 0):

This is known kernel bug for that specific Wifi driver.
The simple fix if your laptop is dual booted is to reboot into windows then into Linux again.
[The kernel bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=216386)
There have been fixes that turn off the ability to put it into low power state but I have noot  tried it myself (although I do in fact have the same problem). More info about them can be found [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=260589)