# How to upgrade the Debian 10 kernel from backports without recompiling it from scratch

Tags: linux, debian, linux-kernel

I'm running Debian 10 on an i9-9900k on a Gigabyte Aorus Pro motherboard (using the integrated Intel graphics chipset) and an nVIDIA RTX 2080Ti graphics card. I have two monitors. I want to have monitor B working with the nVIDIA card and monitor A with the Intel integrated chipset. The problem is that only monitor B is working now. Monitor A is turned off. Maybe there is something bad with the secondary graphic card, because Debian disables the card that's not the most important. I want to enable it. Someone told me that the kernel that I'm using (4.19) is old and it does not support the Intel chipset of the motherboard. I would like to update it, but I don't know how to do that. He said also that it is in the backports. So a couple of lines should be enough. I tried to compile a new kernel from scratch, version 5.3.2, using the default settings, but it didn't work, in fact it freezes during boot. So, my question is: how can I easily upgrade the Debian 10 kernel, from 4.19 at least to a version that allows me to enable the Intel chipset and also `firmware-misc-nonfree`?

Answer (score 26):

Adapting [my Debian 9 answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/420682/86440) to Debian 10:

- enable backports:

  ```
  echo deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib non-free | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/buster-backports.list
  sudo apt update
  ```
- install the backported kernel:

  ```
  sudo apt install -t buster-backports linux-image-amd64
  ```

  (the new kernel will be installed alongside your current kernel, so you can always boot the latter if things go wrong)
- install the firmware:

  ```
  sudo apt install -t buster-backports firmware-linux
  ```

As of this writing, this will install version [5.7.10](https://tracker.debian.org/news/1164996/accepted-linux-5710-1bpo101-source-into-buster-backports-buster-backports/) of the kernel, with the firmware from [August 2020](https://tracker.debian.org/news/1175063/accepted-firmware-nonfree-20200817-1bpo101-source-into-buster-backports/).

Comment: Is installing `firmware-linux` necessary? And regardless of answer, how to install firmware for new kernel without `contrib` and `non-free` in apt sources?

Comment: @metablaster are you using Debian 10?

Comment: I'm on Debian 12 (12.4) should I ask a new question?

Comment: @metablaster [you already know how to install packaged from backports on Debian 12](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/767991/86440), installing a backported kernel is the same; you can’t install backported firmware because there is none.

Comment: thank you I understand, but if there were backported firmware would that be necessary to install for the new kernel to function properly? and I suppose it should be possible without `contrib` and `non-free` firmware in that case? reason I'm asking this is because you included the command in your answer here.