# Cannot bring up the wifi adapter in debian buster RTL8822be

Tags: debian, wifi, realtek

I recently installed Debian Buster on my lenovo - legion - laptop with KDE. But I cannot bring up the WIFI no matter how I googled and tried different founded solutions. I'm sort of new user in linux world. can you help me out to what to do to troubleshoot and solve the problem? thanks in advance.

Output of `lspci -knn |grep -i net -A2` is:

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822]
        Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [17aa:b023]
        Kernel driver in use: r8822be
--
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
        Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:38c2]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169
```

Also, I have to mention that I added `contrib` and `non-free` to my sources list and I have installed `firmware-realtek`. But nothing changed.

Comment: @artemstashkinov thanks to advice. I'm looking for a solution to stay on Debian. 

Comment: Welcome, Please edit your question by adding the output of `lspci -knn |grep -i net -A2`

Comment: @GAD3R thanks to help. I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK! Solution is found. The problem is not with the hardware or driver at all. The main issue is the kernel that Debian Buster is using which seems is not compatible with some new hardwares. To solve that (thanks to @[StephenKitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86440/stephen-kitt)) we have to [upgrade the Kernel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/545609/111995):

1. Enable backports source:

   ```
   echo deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib non-free | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/buster-backports.list
   sudo apt update
   ```
2. Install the backported Kernel alongside the current Kernel:

   ```
   sudo apt install -t buster-backports linux-image-amd64
   ```
3. Install the backported firmware:

   ```
   sudo apt install -t buster-backports firmware-linux firmware-linux-nonfree
   ```
4. Reboot

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```

And then:

5. Install the backported realtek firmware

   ```
   sudo apt install buster-backports firmware-realtek
   ```
6. Reboot again. And you are good to go.