# How do I find out if a device is supported by Debian?

Tags: debian, drivers, ethernet

I couldn't install Debian on my laptop, because "No Ethernet card was detected". I'm hoping to try installation again when the driver is supported by Debian officially, but how do I find out when it is ready?

Currently I can find only https://wiki.debian.org/DeviceDatabase/PCI and https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/amd64/ch02s01.en.html but I don't see much relevant information there.

(the Ethernet card is `Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (13) I219-V (rev 20)`)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there’s no straightforward answer, or even list of devices to look up; the wiki page you linked to was intended as such but hasn’t been updated in a while.

However, support for most devices is determined by the kernel, so one can check there to at least determine a “not earlier than” version. In your case, the device in question uses PCI id 8086:15FC; support for that [was added to the kernel in 5.5](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=fb776f5d57ee0). The next version of Debian will have [version 5.10 of the kernel](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/linux), so as long as support for the device is enabled there (and in your case, it is), Debian 11 will be installable directly on your system.

Version 5.10 of the kernel is also available in Debian backports but that’s harder to use from the installer. If you can install Debian 10 on your system using some other network device, or one of the full installation images, and can provide network access, you can install the backported kernel [by following the instructions posted in another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/545609/86440).

Answer (score 0):

You need to get an Internet connection (USB WIFI) to continue the installation and installing the required packages:

```
sudo apt install make linux-image-$(uname -r)
sudo mkdir /usr/local/src/e1000e
cd $_
```

Download the tarball from [Intel](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/15817/Intel-Network-Adapter-Driver-for-PCI-E-Gigabit-Network-Connections-under-Linux-?product=71307) to `/usr/local/src/e1000e`

```
tar zxf e1000e-3.8.4.tar.gz
cd e1000e-3.8.4/src/
sudo make install
sudo rmmod e1000e; sudo modprobe e1000e
sudo update-initramfs -u
```