# Intel firmware installing on Debian Buster (10.8) problems

Tags: debian, intel, firmware

Trying to use Debian 10.8 on a recently acquired MSI Modern 15 A10M (Model Name: MS-1551).
While installing i see, that a lot of Intel non-free firmware are missing: [link](https://ibb.co/jVQ0FpV) (jpg too large to upload directly).

From 9 missing firmware i found only 3, including one for wireless adapter (Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560).
What i want is at least to make this wifi work.
**My steps**:

1. Copy all found *.ucode files (*33.ucode, *34.ucode, *38.ucode) to `/lib/firmware`
2. Reboot my system.

After reboot `dmesg | grep iwlwifi` shows this:

```
[    3.052012] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 38.755cfdd8.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.109249] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9560, REV=0x354
[    8.257492] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to load firmware chunk!
[    8.257512] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
[    8.257520] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi device config registers:
[    8.257598] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000000: 02f08086 00100406 02800000 00800010 b1314004 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    8.257611] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00348086 00000000 000000c8 00000000 0000010b
[    8.257618] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
[    8.257670] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000000: 00489004 00000040 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    8.257682] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 00000020: 00000011 0c040005 00000351 d55555d5 d55555d5 d55555d5 80008040 001f0040
[    8.257716] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[    8.257755] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[    8.270358] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 8 [0x0bad1122]
[    8.282665] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

`lspci` shows this:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b61 (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9b41 (rev 02)
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 02f9
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 02ed
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 02ef
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 02f0
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 02e8
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 02e0
00:19.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 02c5
00:19.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 02c6
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b0 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b4 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0284
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 02c8
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 02a3
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 02a4
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Kingston Technologies Device 500d (rev 01)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981
```

Guess `Intel Corporation Device*` are not recognized devices.

`uname -r` shows this:

```
4.19.0-14-amd64
```

`uname -v` shows this:

```
#1 SMP Debian 4.19.171-2 (2021-01-30)
```

After shutdown OS could not be loaded due to aforementioned firmware loading errors - had to delete *.ucode - files from `/lib/firmware`.

So, questions are:
How to make .ucode loading work?  (at least wi-fi)
Is it possible to make it on my own?
Or have to wait for a fresh kernel version?

*Btw*, Graphics works ok (Xfce), usb wi-fi adapter worked almost out-of-box.
Thanks in advance.

**UPD**
Also shutdown/reboot/hibernation problems are observed sometimes - it does not work in a proper way.
Kinda system goes to shutdown - but keyboard is still highlighted.
Or system goes hibernation - and you can't awake it, have to shutdown manually and turn on again.
Suspect these are all due to lack of other firmware.

Comment: This won’t help with your wi-fi firmware, but you might want [to try the latest backport kernel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/545609/86440) — there’s a decent chance it will improve your suspend support. Firmware is in `firmware-iwlwifi` but I’m not sure that contains all the file you need yet.

Comment: @StephenKitt, thank you. But installing backport kernel broke second nvme mounting, and OS boot at all. So, installed from beginning (3rd time). I am a newcomer in linuxware, so feel a lot of pain in beginning, lmao. By the way, system itself works very quickly, despite firmware missing.