# Installation of "darling" on Debian 10 is failing

Tags: debian, make, macos

I'm trying to install [`darling`](https://www.darlinghq.org/) to Debian 10, but it is failing.

I've got two .deb files from [here](https://github.com/darlinghq/darling/releases), the first is just darling, and the second is darling-dkms.

Trying to install the first one, I get the following dependency error:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configurtion of darling:
  darling depends on libc6 (>= 2.32); however:
    Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.28-10.
  darling depends on libc6-i386 (>= 2.32); however:
    Version of libc6-i386 on system is 2.28-10
  darling depends on darling-dkms; however:
    Package darling-dkms is not installed
```

I tried running `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, but it didn't fix the issue

The second package is no better: trying to download it, I get a build error:

```
'make' -C lkm/ MIGDIR=/usr/src/darling-mach=0.1/miggen MIGDIR_REL=../miggen....(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel 4.19.0-16-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/darling-mach/0.1/build/make.log for more information.
```

([the log file](https://pastebin.com/BswMm0DR))

I've tried stright away compilling the githup repo, but it was not any better.

I have gcc, clang, make and cmake installed, I'm not sure what is wrong thou. Any help with resolving this issue will be greatly appreciated!

P. s. I am very new to Unix-like systems, so just have that in mind

Answer (score 1):

Those packages are built for Ubuntu 20.10 and won’t work on Debian 10.

You’ll need to build Darling from source; the project provides [detailed build instructions](https://docs.darlinghq.org/build-instructions.html) which include instructions for Debian 10. Unfortunately these instructions can’t work on Debian 10 because the build requires Clang 9 (Debian 10 has Clang 7) and kernel 5.0 or later (Debian 10 has 4.19 by default; 5.10 is available in Buster backports).

Since you’re new to all this, I recommend waiting a few weeks for the release of Debian 11, upgrading to that and trying again (Debian 11 will have everything needed to build Darling).

Comment: They didn't quite work, the "make" command made the following error: https://pastebin.com/ncSAFDQN, and the "make lkm" makes this error: https://pastebin.com/L1RRRjiz

Comment: Sorry, it appears the project can no longer be built on Debian 10...

Comment: For anyone who wants to do that on Debian 10, the upgrading of the kernel is pretty straightforward, it is well described in this article https://jensd.be/968/linux/install-a-newer-kernel-in-debian-10-buster-stable (not sure if it's the "right way", but it works)

Comment: The kernel upgrade process is also described [in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/545609/86440). As far as a release date for Debian 11 goes, it’s still up in the air, it could be late May but more likely June. (There are some installation problems to resolve, see [this thread](https://lists.debian.org/debian-release/2021/04/msg00187.html) for details.)

Comment: Incidentally, the article you linked to recommends running `sudo apt -t buster-backports upgrade`, which one should *never* do.

Comment: Backports have valid reasons for their use, but trying to use them just to squeeze in a future update is definitely not one of them.